# How to split a line of a Pandas dataframe to two lines on a specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

Let's say I have data like this

```
    id      Date        Time_Start  Time_End          start              stop           split

0   011     2017-08-01  20:20   21:40   2017-08-01 20:20:00     2017-08-01 21:40:00     False
1   012     2017-08-01  17:15   19:12   2017-08-01 17:15:00     2017-08-01 19:12:00     True
2   013     2017-08-01  15:46   16:20   2017-08-01 15:46:00     2017-08-01 16:20:00     False
```

and the cut time is at 18:00 of each day. So, for example, "012" should be split to two rows
and the stop column of the first one should update to 2017-08-01 17:59:00 while the start of second row will be 2017-08-01 18:00:00 and the rest stay the same

```
    id      Date        Time_Start  Time_End          start              stop              split    birth_date
    0   011     2017-08-01  20:20   21:40   2017-08-01 20:20:00     2017-08-01 21:40:00     False   2017-08-01
    1   012     2017-08-01  17:15   19:12   2017-08-01 17:15:00     2017-08-01 17:59:00     True    2017-08-01
    1   012     2017-08-01  17:15   19:12   2017-08-01 18:00:00     2017-08-01 19:12:00     True    2017-08-02
    2   013     2017-08-01  15:46   16:20   2017-08-01 15:46:00     2017-08-01 16:20:00     False   2017-08-01
```

Note that I also want to create a new column call "birth_date" at the end if the stop time before 18:00 the "birth_date" will be the same day as "date" but if after the cut, the "birth_date" will be the following day.

below are the code that I've been working with thus far and I'm stuck where I am asking. So, any help will be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd    
from datetime import datetime, time

def make_date_time(df):
    df["start"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"].apply(str) + " " + df["Time_Start"])
    df["stop"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"].apply(str) + " " + df["Time_End"])
    def check_date_time(df):
        if df["start"] > df["stop"]:
            df["stop"] += pd.Timedelta(days=1)
        return df["stop"]
    df["stop"] = df.apply(check_date_time, axis=1)
    return df

def in_cut(df):
    reference = df["start"].replace(hour=18, minute=0, second=0)
    if df["start"] <= df["stop"]:
        return df["start"] <= reference < df["stop"]
    else:
        return df["start"] <= reference or reference < df["stop"]



data = {"id":["011","012","013"], "Date": ["2017-08-01", "2017-08-01", "2017-08-01"], "Time_Start":["20:20", "17:15", "15:46"], "Time_End":["21:40", "19:12", "16:20"]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df = make_date_time(df)
df["split"] = False
df["stop"] = df.apply(check_date_time, axis=1)
df["split"] = df.apply(in_cut, axis=1)
df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding of the problem, you want the stop and start time to be updated wherever split is True.
Below is my approach (Its needs some improvement I guess.. :) ). Hope this helps.

```
import datetime

next_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(df.columns))
next_df['BirthDate'] = ''
pos_new = 0
pos_old = 0
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['split'][i]:
        temp = list(df.iloc[i])
        print(temp)
        df['stop'][i] = (df['stop'][i]).replace(hour=17, minute=59, second=0)

        temp_list = list(df.loc[pos_old])
        temp_list.append(df.loc[pos_old][0])

        next_df.loc[pos_new] = temp_list
        pos_old+=1
        pos_new+=1

        temp[4] = temp[4].replace(hour=18, minute=0, second=0)
        print(temp)
        #conversion of date
        temp_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(temp[0], "%Y-%m-%d")
        temp.append((temp_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
        next_df.loc[pos_new] = temp

        pos_new+=1
    else:
        temp_list = list(df.loc[pos_old])
        temp_list.append(df.loc[pos_old][0])
        next_df.loc[pos_new] = temp_list
        pos_old+=1
        pos_new+=1
```

**Edit**

I had to make some changes to your code in order to successfully produce what I want. As this solution does what I want although it's not quite pythonic. So, I'll accept it as the correct answer then.

The following is the code that I have updated.

```
import datetime

next_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(df.columns))
next_df['BirthDate'] = ''
pos_new = 0
pos_old = 0
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['split'][i]:
        # get one row at a time and converse it to a list
        temp = list(df.iloc[i])

        # update stop time to 17:59:00
        df['stop'][i] = (df['stop'][i]).replace(hour=17, minute=59, second=0)

        temp_list = list(df.loc[pos_old])
        # append birth adte to the list
        temp_list.append(temp[4].date().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
        # add this row to new df
        next_df.loc[pos_new] = temp_list
        # update the pointers for old and new df 
        pos_old+=1
        pos_new+=1
        temp[4] = temp[4].replace(hour=18, minute=0, second=0)

        # conversion of date
        temp_date = temp[4].date() 
        # plus one to date as this case is considered to happen in the following day
        temp.append((temp_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
        # add the new row to df
        next_df.loc[pos_new] = temp
        # update the pointer of new df for the split row
        pos_new+=1
    else:
        temp_list = list(df.loc[pos_old])
        temp_list.append(temp[4].date().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
        next_df.loc[pos_new] = temp_list
        # update the pointers for old and new df 
        pos_old+=1
        pos_new+=1

next_df
```